# How do you contact google patents

Tags: google

Has anyone every contact google patents.

In a recent gazette, I find many images missing.

See here: http://www.google.com/patents/USD690487

They have a non-committal feedback page.  I have given feedback!!

[image]

Comment: All 30 figures are in the downloadable PDF. They are also all in the main screen. On my iPad I see left and right arrows for horizontal a scrolling.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite I have added a screen shot.  Are you saying you dont see this?  When I click on those links titled "patent Drawing" it shows a blank screen.  Note that I have seen earlier patents which show the image

Comment: I think you are correct. If your goal is to see the figures, they are in the downloadable and the viewable PDF.

Answer (score -1):

You can contact them on twitter @googlepatents.  I am still waiting for their response :-(

Comment: twitter account was @googlepatent - don't think it is actively used